# installing pip install musicplayer to import module in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
pip install musicplayer
Collecting musicplayer
  Using cached musicplayer-1.20141030.091600.tar.gz (51 kB)
Could not build wheels for musicplayer, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: musicplayer
    Running setup.py install for musicplayer ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\anil dubey\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ANILDU~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-51dz75b4\\musicplayer\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ANILDU~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-51dz75b4\\musicplayer\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ANILDU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8cd6b6hc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\anil dubey\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\musicplayer'
         cwd: C:\Users\ANILDU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-51dz75b4\musicplayer\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'musicplayer' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\anil dubey\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ANILDU~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-51dz75b4\\musicplayer\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ANILDU~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-51dz75b4\\musicplayer\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ANILDU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8cd6b6hc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\anil dubey\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\musicplayer' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

It says that you need Visual Studio for C++ in order to get musicplayer. Try installing it and see if there is an error.

Also, the first error states that you haven't installed pip properly, because it says that the wheels package for pip isn't installed.

Install pip properly, then try again.